# How to use the tar -I option

Tags: solaris, tar

I'm trying to tar up all the *.class files only on a Solaris box under a certain directory. 
Reading the man pages for tar made it seem like the -I option is what I wanted.
This is what I've tried from the dir in question:

```
find . -name "*.class" >> ~/includes.txt
tar cvf ~/classfiles.tar -I ~/includes.txt
```

From that I get:

```
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
/home/myhomedir/includes.txt
```

And the ~/classfiles.tar files is garbage.

I don't have write permission on the dir where the *.class files are so I need to have the tar written to my home dir. Could someone tell me where I have gone wrong? What tar magic should I use?

Comment: did you check to make sure that the includes.txt file looks OK on output?

Comment: what do you mean by "garbage"?

Comment: When I do a: tar tvf classfiles.tar, I get:
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: 428 garbage bytes ignored at end of archive
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check which tar you are running.  That message about removing the leading slash is a **gtar** (GNU tar) message, and the -I option you are trying to use is a Sun tar option (which lives in /bin/tar).

(at least the above is all true on my Solaris machine)

Comment: Is there an equivalent gnu tar option?